# Dropping factors by the frequency of level occurance

Tags: r, data.table

```
DATA = data.table(col1 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.99)),
              col2 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.98)),
              col3 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.90)),
              col4 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.97)))
```

I have a large data set that contains numerous factors. For some of them there is a huge disproportion between two levels `0-1`. I would like to find a way to drop variables for which one of the levels contain less than 2% of total observations.  Ideally the outcome would be just the `data.table` with variables that are more balanced (both levels represent at least 2% of the total observations).

Comment: I do not understand why my post got downvoted? Is anything unclear or should I state the issue in another manner?

Comment: To me everything is clear and you provided an example.. so up again. Btw: here is a very similar question, but looking for the absolute number of observations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259194/elegant-way-to-drop-rare-factor-levels-from-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are more elegant ways, but here is a solution:

```
library(data.table)

DATA = data.table(col1 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.99)),
                  col2 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.98)),
                  col3 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.90)),
                  col4 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.97)))

occuranceList <- list()

for(colname in colnames(DATA)){
  occuranceList[[colname]] <- DATA[, list(portion = .N/nrow(DATA), variable = colname), by = colname]
}

occuranceDT <- rbindlist(occuranceList)

DATA[, c(occuranceDT$variable[occuranceDT$portion < 0.02]) := NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
library(data.table)

DATA = data.table(col1 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.99)),
                  col2 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.98)),
                  col3 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.90)),
                  col4 = factor(rbinom(1000,1,.97)))

colnames <- copy(names(DATA))
  for(colname in colnames){
    if(any(table(DATA[, ..colname])/nrow(DATA) < 0.02)){
      DATA[, c(colname) := NULL]
    }
  }
```